# Get posts from post author - WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to make a section that shows the posts created by the user that created the current post. I need to show them obviously excluding the current post and according to a certain type of post (event).

I have this code, but it is not working. Can someone think of how to help me?

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
    'author'        =>  $post->post_author;
    'type'          => $post_meta['_listing_type'][0] == 'event',
    'order'         =>  'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $eventos = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $eventos as $evento ) {
        $output .= '<div>'.$evento.'</div>';
    endforeach;

    if(!empty($eventos)) : ?> 

        <div id="listing-eventosartista" class="listing-section">
            <h3 class="listing-desc-headline margin-top-60 margin-bottom-30"><?php esc_html_e('Eventos del artista','listeo_core'); ?></h3>
                <div class="single-item">
                    <?php echo $output; ?>
                </div>

        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of things. You've got an illegal semi-colon in your `$args` array, `type` should be `post_type`, I'm also not entirely sure you need that weird comparison operator in there?

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'author'         => $post->post_author,
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

Also make sure that `$post` is set, depending on *where* you're calling this, there may not be an instantiated/global `$post` object.

This is also assuming you're using an actual `post_type` called `event`, otherwise if you're checking regular posts for the meta field `'_listing_type'`, you'll need to drop the `post_type` argument, and add a [`meta_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) argument instead - note that this is inherently slow on large databases because the `postmeta` table isn't indexed by default. Also note that `meta_query` is an *array of arrays*.

That query would end up looking something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'author'         => $post->post_author,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'meta_key'   => '_listing_type',
            'meta_value' => 'event'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This worked for me! But I used `key` and `value` instead of `meta_key` and `meta_value` Thank you!